# App crashes the second time I open the Android Settings

Tags: android, android-intent

I have a button in a fragment than open Android settings.

```
((Button)view.findViewById(R.id.fragment_settings_androidsettings_button)).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        startActivityForResult(new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_SETTINGS), 0);
    }
});
```

Every second time I click on the button, my app crashes with the following log message:

```
showStatusIcon on inactive InputConnection
```

This doesn't happen the first time.

How can I debug and solve this issue? Thanks

Comment: Can you please show more of the logcat? Also, what result are you expecting to get back and do something with?

Comment: It works on my galaxy s4

Comment: cricket_007, I do not need anything back, so I have changed to startActivity, but nothing changed.

Comment: My logcat contains:

03-21 19:52:10.521 11364-11364/com.app W/IInputConnectionWrapper: showStatusIcon on inactive InputConnection
03-21 19:52:10.781 11364-11364/com.app W/dalvikvm: threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41605270)
03-21 19:52:10.791 11364-11364/com.app I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 11364 SIG: 9